# Change Class component to function component with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I'm learning react hook and trying to change my class component to a function component and fetch the data with hooks using useEffect and useState, but it's not working. This is my class component and below I will put the draft of the function component, I think there is something wrong in the way I use the useEffect. All help will be appreciated.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Shop = () =>  {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/products`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
      setProducts(products);
    });
  })
  
  return (
    <div>
      {
        products.map(product => (
          <div className="shop ml-5 mt-4" key={product.id}>
            <img className="image" src={product.image} alt=""/><br></br>
            <button className= "mt-4 btn btn-light">QUICKSHOP</button>
            <button className="mt-4 btn btn-light">ADD TO CART</button>
            <p className="mt-4"> {product.title}</p>
            <p>{product.price}</p>
          </div>
        )) }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Shop;
```

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class component, you want to run `getProducts` on mount, but in the functional component, you run the `fetch` on *every render*. Add an empty dependency array to the `useEffect` to ensure it only runs on mount, rather than every time.

You also need to use `setProducts(response);`, not `setProducts(products);` - `products` is the existing (empty) state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`/products`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      setProducts(response);
    });
}, [])
```